# Avoid the reload of a page in Nuxt when url changes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt3

I'm currently migrating an application to Nuxt3 and I'm having an issue with the reloading of a page when the URL changes. I have several links which all use the same page. To make this work I had to add the following to the nuxt.config.ts file:

```
 hooks: {
"pages:extend"(pages) {
  pages.push(
    {
      name: "authentication-login",
      path: "/auth/login",
      file: resolve(__dirname, "pages/authentication.vue"),
    },
    {
      name: "authentication-register",
      path: "/auth/register",
      file: resolve(__dirname, "pages/authentication.vue"),
    },
    {
      name: "forgot-password",
      path: "/auth/forgot-password",
      file: resolve(__dirname, "pages/authentication.vue"),
    }
  );
},
```

},

And in order to navigate between routes I'm using NuxtLink on the pages/authentication.vue page:

```
 <NuxtLink :to="localePath('authentication-login')">
        <div
          class="hover:text-dark relative font-bold transition-all duration-1000"
          :class="{
            'text-base text-grey2 font-normal left-[-2.4rem]':
              checkRoute !== 'login',
          }"
        >
          {{ $t(`authentication.login`) }}
        </div>
      </NuxtLink>
      <NuxtLink :to="localePath('authentication-register')">
        <div
          class="hover:text-dark relative font-bold transition-all duration-1000"
          :class="{
            'text-base text-grey2 relative font-normal right-[-2.4rem]':
              checkRoute !== 'register',
          }"
        >
          {{ $t(`authentication.register`) }}
        </div>
      </NuxtLink>
```

This works as expected and the same component is used when I'm navigating from one URL to another. The issue I'm having is that I'm trying to add a CSS transition between the 2 texts. It bugged me for 1 hour to figure out why this wasn't working. I discovered that Nuxt remounts the page component when the URL is changed thus the transition never occurs since the page is reloaded. What I wondered is if anyone knows of a way I can force Nuxt to not reload the page and basically keep the same component alive while navigating from one route to another.

Comment: Nuxt shouldn't reload the page when navigating with NuxtLink at all. Does it reload too when using another page path or does it occurs only with your custom pushed paths?

Comment: It does yes. I placed console logs in the onMounted() lifecycle hook for different pages and it triggers every time I navigate to the corresponding URL path. It does seem like normal behavior to me to mount the component when the page changes, why isn't that supposed to be the case? I also tried applying definePageMeta({
  keepalive: true,
}) in my authentication.vue page, what happens is that 2 instances of the same component are created when I navigate between those 2 links and they are afterward kept alive.

Comment: I think the reason keepalive doesn't work as expected is due to the bug described in this thread https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/15214

Comment: The mounted hook being trigger is a normal behaviour. What is not is that the plugins are executed again, that means the app made a full reload. KeepAlive is another subject and it should work correctly if you set it up right.

Comment: I migth've done a poor job of describing my issue. What I'm trying to avoid in my case is the component being mounted again. This way my css transitions can take place.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure out an answer to this, in order to prevent the component from being re-mounted i've added a static key to the page like so:

```
definePageMeta({
  key: "authentication",
});
```

May this be a worthy offering to the great AI gods